# Why are differential forms so convenient? (In applied mathematics)

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

This is a soft question to understand better why differential forms are so useful, especially in applied mathematics.

I own [Tu's - Introduction to Manifolds](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xQsTJJGsgs4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=introduction%20to%20smooth%20manifolds%20tu%20pdf&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR6ZjFrs7lAhXkoVwKHW3UASkQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), and I'll quote the introduction of section 18:

> Differential forms are generalizations of real-valued functions on a manifold. Instead
>   of assigning to each point of the manifold a number, a differential k-form assigns to
>   each point a k-covector on its tangent space. For k = 0 and 1, differential k-forms are
>   functions and covector fields respectively Differential forms play a crucial role in manifold
>   theory. First and foremost, they are intrinsic objects
>   associated to any manifold, and so can be used to
>   construct diffeomorphism invariants of a manifold.
>   In contrast to vector fields, which are also intrinsic
>   to a manifold, differential forms have a far richer algebraic structure. Due to the existence of the wedge
>   product, a grading, and the exterior derivative, the
>   set of smooth forms on a manifold is both a graded
>   algebra and a differential complex. Such an algebraic structure is called a differential graded algebra. Moreover, the differential complex of smooth
>   forms on a manifold can be pulled back under a
>   smooth map, making the complex into a contravariant functor called the de Rham complex of the manifold. We will eventually construct the de Rham cohomology of a manifold from the de Rham complex.
>   Because integration of functions on a Euclidean space depends on a choice of
>   coordinates and is not invariant under a change of coordinates, it is not possible to
>   integrate functions on a manifold. The highest possible degree of a differential form
>   is the dimension of the manifold. Among differential forms, those of top degree turn
>   out to transform correctly under a change of coordinates and are precisely the objects
>   that can be integrated. The theory of integration on a manifold would not be possible
>   without differential forms.

From this introduction, and plus what the text actually covers on the subject, it seems to me that the main advantage of the differential forms over vector fields is their algebraic structure (which is much richer than the vector fields one).

However I do struggle to understand if once I get used to the formalism it actually makes easier to model certain geometric problems. There's another book from the same author ([Tu's - Differential geometry](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bmsmDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=tu%20differential%20geometry%20pdf&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi55uzpr87lAhVQh1wKHcKACwsQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)) where the formalism of forms is used to derive the structure equations, which are still differential forms.

I own such book as well, but I also own [Do Carmo's - Riemannian Geometry](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ct91XCWkWEUC&dq=riemannian%20geometry%20do%20carmo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8jLKHsM7lAhWdThUIHarbDoYQ6AEIKTAA), and I've been reading the three of them lately.

The thing is Do Carmo doesn't seem to make use of differential forms at all to develop his theory (except in the exercises), Tu instead uses differential forms as I mentioned.

This difference strikes me, since I can't quite figure what sort of "modelling" advantage differential forms give over normal vector fields to model certain problems.

There're also few papers (Computer Graphics papers) that I've been reading through lately where the differential forms formalism is actually used to design certain algorithms to process meshes, so they must have some modelling advantage that I don't understand.

Can anyone clarify?

**Update**: As further clarification I think I can give, I'm asking from the applied mathematics point of view. For example in triangular meshes processing, tools from differential geometry are used to compute laplacian, gradient etc, but the methods I'm aware don't really use differential forms, but I'm aware from some papers I've been reading in the last few months that differential forms are somehow used to model some problems, I can't understand though why such formalism is actually better in some situations.

Please let me know if you like some quotes from some of the paper I'm talking about.

Comment: I am not qualified to give an answer, but I will comment. Forms by themselves are extremely useful when you want to discuss the *topology* of the manifold (see the later chapters of "Introduction to Manifolds" by Tu, specifically the stuff about de Rham cohomology). But, it seems to me, the *geometry* only really comes to the fore once you start talking about manifolds equipped with (Riemannian) metrics. This is basically why "Introduction to Manifolds" does not have the words "Differential Geometry" in the title.

Comment: As propaganda for differential forms, I'll suggest the proof (originally due to Chern) of Gauss-Bonnet — just for surfaces. It is immediate from Stokes's Theorem and the structure equations (which are concise and powerful formulations of the Codazzi and Gauss equations). If you've not seen it before, you can see the main ideas in Section 3 of Chapter 3 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). Indeed, differential forms are highly useful in differential geometry, far beyond deRham cohomology.

Comment: @WillR what do you mean exactly with "discuss the topology"?

Comment: @TedShifrin I aspire to reach the point where I can answer a question by citing myself.

Comment: @user8469759: I mean when you care about topological properties of manifolds, i.e., properties which are shared by homeomorphic topological spaces. Things like the Euler characteristic and ranks of homology groups fall into this category. Forms *are* useful far beyond this - see Ted's comment - but my point is that if you want to see how forms help to understand *geometry*, then you should look to see where and how they arise in passages that involve metrics and connections.

Comment: @WillR I think also, in practice, you want also to optimize or find some optimal function defined on a manifold. I was wondering if in this situations using forms might provide some help.

Comment: @user8469759: Oh! You really *mean* "model certain problems", as in, more applied mathematics? In that case, you should edit your question to be more specific, and perhaps try to find more appropriate tags. Right now, your question is being looked at by pure geometers, which is probably the wrong audience.

Comment: @WillR Just edited the question, but about the tags not sure which one I should use.

Comment: From the point of view of applications, consider discrete calculus = discrete exterior calculus = calculus of discrete differential forms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_calculus